# Hodge-Tate representations

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-hodge-theory

I know that the p-adic representaions from geometries are de Rham representations and hence they are Hodge-Tate 
representations. Then, are there (more than 2-dimensional) Hodge-Tate representations not coming from geometries?  If there are, let me know 
the references. Sorry if it is trivial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every de Rham representation is Hodge--Tate, but the converse is not true -- there are Hodge--Tate representations which are not de Rham, and thus cannot appear in geometry. (Examples of these arise in dimension 2 via the theory of p-adic modular forms.)

I don't think anyone knows how to characterise, even conjecturally, the p-adic Galois representations of a p-adic field which come from geometry; there is a precise conjecture for Galois representations of number fields, due to Fontaine and Mazur, but as yet this has no local analogue.

Comment: A simpler example would be a non-trivial extension of $Q_p$ by $Q_p(-1)$.

Comment: Thank Loeffler and Berger. I was very foolish. It suffices to find an example of Hodge-Tate but not de Rham. I am very shameful. Anyway, I did not know that there is not the local characterization of ``geometric origin" and so thank Loeffler for your comments.